# Using OKHTTP in Android to request a GET service from ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, okhttp

i have this problem that kept me thinking,I'm using `OkHTTp` to connect to the my **WebAPi** service.The problem is i keep getting "null" result on the android side. Here is the Android side code:

```
public class OkHttpHandlerIncoming extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String URL = "http://localhost:8306/api/uconnectservice";

    String JsonStringObject;

    public OkHttpHandlerIncoming() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(params[0]).build();
        // Request request = new
        // Request.Builder().url(params[0]).post(formBody).build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.e("Execute Request", request.toString());
            if (!response.isSuccessful())
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response.toString());
            return response.body().string();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

and i make the call from main thread as follows

```
public void DATAFROMSERVICE(){
        StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder("Result:");

        OkHttpHandlerIncoming client = new OkHttpHandlerIncoming();

        String result = null;
        try {
            result = client.execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("From Service", outputText.append(result + "\n").toString());

    }
////////////////////////////////////////
Also here is the code from the server side

  public class UConnectServiceController : ApiController
    {
        private IUconnectRepository _UconnectHandler;

        public UConnectServiceController()
        {
            _UconnectHandler = new UconnectRepository();
        }

        public UConnectServiceController(IUconnectRepository repository)
        {
            if (_UconnectHandler == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
            }
            _UconnectHandler = repository;
        }

        /////I am calling this service-> GET api/uconnectservice
        public List<AcountTypesRegistered> Get()
        {
            return _UconnectHandler.GetAll();
        }
```

code continues...

Please can someone guide me on what is going wrong or any better suggestions
                              thnks

BTW here is my Log cat:

```
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:483)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at com.nickSoft.unics_alpha.accountdetails.DATAFROMSERVICE(accountdetails.java:198)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at com.nickSoft.unics_alpha.accountdetails.onCreate(accountdetails.java:120)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at com.nickSoft.Connections.OkHttpHandlerIncoming.doInBackground(OkHttpHandlerIncoming.java:53)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at com.nickSoft.Connections.OkHttpHandlerIncoming.doInBackground(OkHttpHandlerIncoming.java:1)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/System.err(26811):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-13 03:20:54.360: E/From Service(26811): Result:null
12-13 03:20:54.360: W/dalvikvm(26811): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ced88)
12-13 03:20:54.360: E/test(26811): Exception
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): Process: com.nickSoft.unics_alpha, PID: 26811
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at com.nickSoft.Connections.OkHttpHandlerIncoming.doInBackground(OkHttpHandlerIncoming.java:53)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at com.nickSoft.Connections.OkHttpHandlerIncoming.doInBackground(OkHttpHandlerIncoming.java:1)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-13 03:20:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(26811):    ... 4 more
```

///AFTER CODE EDIT I GET THIS LOGCAT////////////////

```
12-13 03:58:36.640: I/ActivityManager(28324): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41a7bde0 time:12169583
12-13 03:59:30.560: W/System.err(29371): java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8306
12-13 03:59:30.560: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:189)
12-13 03:59:30.560: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:173)
12-13 03:59:30.560: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114)
12-13 03:59:30.560: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193)
12-13 03:59:30.560: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
12-13 03:59:30.560: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:33)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:120)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-13 03:59:30.570: W/System.err(29371):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: I would highly recommend checking out https://square.github.io/retrofit/. It uses OkHTTP under the hood by default, but provides for a very simple interaction with an api.

Comment: thnx @Orbit,looking into it

Comment: You are silently swallowing all exceptions with `catch (Exception e) { }` you should add `e.printStackTrace();` in there to help you figure out what is going from with your call

Comment: ok @iagreen included in code ,but still ......

Comment: What does the stacktrace say when you are getting `null`?  Please add that part of your logcat to your question.

Comment: ok @iagreen just added logcat thxs

Comment: have you checked the api using postman or fiddler

Comment: and what is the response string.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from this line --

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(params[0]).build();
```

because you are not passing a `String` to your `AsyncTask` here --

```
result = client.execute().get();
```

based on your code, I would guess that your to pass `URL` in there --

```
result = client.execute().get(URL);
```

OkHttp can execute commands in the background for you.  Your code would be a lot simpler if instead of calling `execute` in an `AsyncTask`, you were to let OkHttp handle the background task for you via an [asynchronous call](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get) using `enqueue`.

Comment: Ok @iagreen looking into it,Thnxs for your input.

Comment: ok  @iagreen but i get another logcat saying i can't connect  (see Question Edit)

Comment: hmm, looks like your server is not receiving connections.  Check to make sure your server is running at the address and port specified in your URL.  You probably need to replace `localhost` with the IP address of your asp machine because `localhost` is going to refer to the android device in this instance and it is unlikely you are running asp on your phone!

Comment: ,true i changed URL to: 192.168.1.102 but i get this logcat: Java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.102 (port 8306) after 10000ms

Comment: Looks like something is up with your asp server, which is outside of my area, so I'm not going to be much more help.

Comment: thnks for the help u provided earlier,